# generating multiple reporting folder in playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

[image]I'm trying to generate multiple reporting folders inside a folder for JUnit and HTML reports, seems like playwright will override the other folder. after tests, I can see only the HTML report folder and other JUnit results won't be available. is there any way to have multiple results folders under one folder?

Comment: What does your configuration look like?

Comment: attached config image

Comment: It is recommended to avoid using images for code. if you post the code, it would be easier for everyone to update it as necessary and include it in the answer.

Comment: due to character limit, I was not able to post the config, hence pasted image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outputDir` is used for another purpose other than test results based on the information available [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-output-dir). So I would recommend against storing test results inside it. Instead, you can do something like this.

```js
const path = require('path');
const resultsDir = path.resolve('./', 'output')

reporter: [ ['json', { outputFile: `${resultsDir}/json/results.json` }] ]
```